# Updating Linkedin API Scope doesn't work unless user removes app

Tags: linkedin-api

I added a new permission to my linkedin api scope and it did not work until I removed my application from my account, then re-authenticated. This is even after I re-authenticated with linkedin, seeing the new scope change in the list. It only worked after I removed the app.

Is there a better way I'm missing? The Linkedin docs don't seem to touch on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well. It seems you need to create a new app to get a new api key... woof.

EDIT:
http://developer.linkedin.com/comment/30279#comment-30279

Confirmation that this is the only option.